# Where could I find U.S. county-level data on the number of smartphone users?

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for panel data at the county, city, or state (worst case) level for the United States showing the **number of smartphone users** or the **size of the smartphone market** in these locations. This could be expressed in either absolute counts or as percentages. Ideally, I would want historical data from 2017 or 2016 to 2008, but anything since 2010 would also work.

Alternatively, I am also looking web device usage data at comparable levels. That is, a look at what type of devices were used to access the web. This, too, would have to cover the same time periods.

I am also open to commercial data sources, but would prefer open data. The closest answer I have found so far was this: [Cellphone vs Smartphone usage?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3665/cellphone-vs-smartphone-usage) but it still doesn't fully answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

It may take a little elbow grease, but the American Community Survey product from the US census seems to have a "Cellular data plan for a smartphone or other mobile device" measurement (variable name "BROADBND"), I took this from the 2017 ACS PUMS DATA DICTIONARY. So if you're willing to munge the data, you should be able to get it at a lower spatial resolution (eg census block or block group) and should be able to get it at the county level. The American Factfinder (Frome US Census) might have a user friendly interface.

Comment: lots of acs data doesn't go beyond the county/locality level; not saying you are wrong, just saying if you aren't certain, this could be wrong.